# Flask-WTF "The CSRF tokens do not match" with AWS ECS and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, flask-wtforms, aws-elb

I have followed this guide:

https://manmohan-bohara.medium.com/aws-container-services-part-1-b147e974c745

so have a Flask app, which is dockerised and running on AWS ECS with a load balancer.

If I run the docker locally and submit any forms which use FlaskWTF it works. However, if I use the ELB url on AWS or the underlying EC2 IP address I get an error

`The CSRF tokens do not match`

I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting this? I think it may be caching issue but can't work out where the caching would be.

Comment: Did you try in a private window ?

Comment: This article has some good hints https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask

Comment: The tutorial you linked does not use `Flask-WTF`.  So what exactly did you changed in the tutorial?

Comment: Can you include a minimally reproducible representative chunk of your Flask code to help us help you?

Comment: Did u try clearing your cookies?